# TaskKill very slow

Tags: windows, service

I have a batch file which uses `taskkill` to stop several services.  The commands look like this:

```
taskkill /s \\myServer /f /fi "Services eq MyService"
```

The problem is that each command takes a really long time (around 1 minute).  Since there are several such commands, the batch file is really slow.

Is there any way to speed up `taskkill`?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `sc stop` instead of killing the service.  It's a preferred method.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742107(WS.10).aspx

Comment: A service will try going through a normal service stop procedure, which can take a little while, but is always safer than a hard process kill. A process kill should only be used when absolutely necessary.

Comment: OK but is `sc` any faster than `taskkill`?  That was my real question.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to ignore that aspect of the question, but I really can't say for sure.  I was hoping you'd test it and let us know.  The answer to that question might be service specific.  Nixphoe's method might help as long as there isn't a specific order that the services must be stopped.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @pk said, if you *must* use taskkill, you could create one bat file for each task to kill, then create a bat file to call each batch file.

Would still be slow for each taskkill to finish, but they would run at the same time, speeding up your full script.

Should look something like this:

```
cmd /c c:\bat\killbatch1.bat
cmd /c c:\bat\killbatch2.bat
cmd /c c:\bat\killbatch3.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried switching to `sc` but it was also very slow.  There is some underlying issue (possibly networking related?) but I haven't been able to find it.

I ended up moving the service stopping code to a .vbs script using WMI using the info [here](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/wmi_services.htm).